# Ubuntu 18.04 HDMI not working lenovo legion y530

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, lenovo, hdmi

my laptop's HDMI port is not working and I don't know why exactly, I am running Ubuntu 18.04 alongside windows, on windows it works just fine.
The laptop uses Nvidia graphics card gtx 1050, I have the latest driver installed (430) and I tried many other versions and did not work including version 390.

I had Ubuntu budgie on this laptop before and it also worked and didn't work after that.

I would appreciate some help with isolating the problem to solve it, is it from the driver or port not detected etc.

Also I might have to say that xrandr doesn't return anything saying that I have and HDMI port

Comment: The only thing that helped me was to diasble the drm setting as stated in this dell support forum thread: https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Mobile-Workstations/External-Monitor-not-working-Ubuntu-nvidia/td-p/6241315 Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue yesterday when I found your question here. I started to work on it two weeks ago and spent a lot of hour to install different distributions. It is not just an ubuntu issue. I have tried ubuntu, fedora, manjaro and all of them had problem with booting the OS and/or detecting HDMI port. There is a guide for Ubuntu here: https://github.com/kfechter/LegionY530Ubuntu/tree/18.04.2-Install-Guide

It didn't solve the HDMI problem for me, but I tried many times and some times I realised I made mistakes, so you should try it if you haven't tried it yet.

Today I have managed to make the HDMI port work and I am not sure what solved it, because at the end, I used Kubuntu 19.04. If you are unable to solve it on Ubuntu 18.04 and you don't insist on using that, it could work for you too. If you don't like KDE, you can install other desktop environment later.

This way I have kernel version 5.0.0 and nvidia-driver-418. Everything works.

The install guide on github mentions [how you can upgrade the kernel using ukuu](https://github.com/kfechter/LegionY530Ubuntu/blob/18.04.2-Install-Guide/Sections/ukuu.md) on Ubuntu 18.04.

Here is how I tried the installation last time with success on wired network connection:

1. I do not have "secure boot" setting in UEFI settings so I disabled "trusted platform" instead.
2. I created a live USB drive using [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) on an other Linux laptop. [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) could work on Windows.
3. The Lenovo Legion Y530 laptop was turned off and the external monitor's HDMI cable was plugged into the laptop.
4. I turned the laptop on and booted the live OS (I pressed F12 key to go to the boot menu).

   1. First I chose the "Linpus Lite" entry which was one of the etries of my USB drive. I could not wait long enough to let it boot, so I rebooted the system and then...
   2. I tried again chosing "USB HDD ..." instead of "Linpus Lite". I don't think it was faster anyway...
5. On the partitioning screen there was no "EFI Partition" to chose and mount so for the first time I did not use EFI.
6. When the installation was done I rebooted the system, pressed F12 again and chose "Samsung HDD ..." (so not the entry containing "EFI")

Suddenly my external monitor was recognized but I am not sure which step solved it (new kernel, Kubuntu, latest Kubuntu, installing without EFI or the combination of them)

Comment: it might be because of the new kernel. but one thing to notice is kernel 5.x was not working with nvidia. maybe its working now.